# Magento2: for several days Very slow website loading

Tags: magento2

I have a dedicated server and two different stores on this server. One store loading perfectly, but with the second store for several days I have a problem with website loading - is too long.

I do not know what it is caused. There is clearly a problem with the magento application, can anyone help us?

```
czasowewyprzedaze.pl

[2018-08-20 04:24:50] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Mgs/claue/pl_PL/priceBox.js' [] []
[2018-08-20 04:25:08] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Mgs/claue/pl_PL/jquery/ui.js' [] []
[2018-08-20 04:25:23] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Mgs/claue/pl_PL/zoom-images.js' [] []
2018-08-20 04:25:47] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Mgs/claue/pl_PL/mgs/owlcarousel.js' [] []
[2018-08-20 04:26:11] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Mgs/claue/pl_PL/mgs/lazyload.js' [] []
[2018-08-20 04:26:31] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Mgs/claue/pl_PL/magnificPopup.js' [] []
[2018-08-20 04:26:46] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Mgs/claue/pl_PL/waypoints.js' [] []
[2018-08-20 04:27:14] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Mgs/claue/pl_PL/jquery/jquery-storageapi.js' [] []

[2018-08-20 04:25:08] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Mgs/claue/pl_PL/jquery/ui.js' [] []
[2018-08-20 04:25:47] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Mgs/claue/pl_PL/mgs/owlcarousel.js' [] []
```

Comment: try to run upgrade and deploy command for this store.

Comment: Some of your theme file is not loading propelry, you might be need Static content deploy

Comment: Thanks for your try help. I have try run:  setup: upgrade, static:di:compile, setup:static-content:deploy -f, it still did not bring any result.